# Как обеспечить поддержу позиционных и именованных аргументов в декораторе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, декоратор

**Добрый день!**

Пытаюсь разобраться с работой декораторов. Хочу, чтобы была поддержка как позиционных, так и именованных аргументов, однако что-то не догоняю.

```
def printing(function):
    def inner(how, *args):
        result = function(how=how, *args)
        print('result =', result)
        return result
    return inner

@printing
def function(how=True, *args):
    if how == True:
        return [arg[::-1] for arg in args]
    else:
        return [arg for arg in args]
    
function(True, 'Тест', 'Тест2', 'Тест3', 'Тест4')
function(how=True, 'Тест', 'Тест2', 'Тест3', 'Тест4')
function(how=False, 'Тест', 'Тест2', 'Тест3', 'Тест4')
```

Выпадает:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Подскажите, как исправить. Буду благодарен за любые комментарии!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Позиционные аргументы в Python всегда должны идти **до** именованных (ошибка буквально говорит, что у вас позиционный параметр идет **после** именованного, что недопустимо). Поэтому, если вы хотите использовать параметр `how` как именованный, передавайте его последним параметром (после `*args`).

При этом, если вы будете передавать его как неименованный параметр, то он будет восприниматься как часть кортежа (`tuple`) параметров `*args`, его нужно вытащить из этого кортежа и передать отдельно.

```
def printing(function):
    def inner(*args, how=None):
        if how is None:
            how = args[-1]
            args = args[:-1]
        
        result = function(*args, how=how)
        print('result =', result)
        return result
    return inner


@printing
def function(*args, how=True):
    if how == True:
        return [arg[::-1] for arg in args]
    else:
        return [arg for arg in args]
    

function('Тест', 'Тест2', 'Тест3', 'Тест4', True)
function('Тест', 'Тест2', 'Тест3', 'Тест4', how=True)
function('Тест', 'Тест2', 'Тест3', 'Тест4', how=False)
```

Вывод:

```
result = ['тсеТ', '2тсеТ', '3тсеТ', '4тсеТ']
result = ['тсеТ', '2тсеТ', '3тсеТ', '4тсеТ']
result = ['Тест', 'Тест2', 'Тест3', 'Тест4']
```